# socket.io 400 bad request cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, websocket, socket.io, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I am working on a web-app which uses socket.io for real time chat purpose.
web-app is developed in MEAN stack.
my front End build is hosted on S3 and powered by cloudfront.
and the back end is on EC2.
Now everything works fine,my APIs are redirected to the EC2 properly as cloudfront cannot handle them.
but I get 400 error for my socket.io
I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

cloudfront has ssl certificate attached but my server still runs on 80.
I haven't used nginx or any server on my ec2 instance.
Also I don't have any ALB initialised.

I know cloudfront doesn't support websockets but what steps I have to take to make it work?

Comment: Since 11/2018 CloudFront support websockets https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-cloudfront-announces-support-for-the-websocket-protocol/ I just can't find anyone who implemented it using **socket.io**

Comment: Hi @Amio.io thanks for replying.
so what else can we use to implement sockets?

Comment: Hey man, we've have tested socket.io and CloudFront. It's compatible!

Comment: Hi Amio, Looks like I've to work on it again to see if it works now or not.
Thanks for replying though ;)